# What is this type of query called, and how can I formulate it?

Tags: mysql, query, relational-theory

I have following tables:

> **events**(event_id, name, description)
>
> **groups**(group_id, event_id, title, description)
>
> **event_group**(event_id, group_id)
>
> **users**(user_id, name, email)
>
> **event_user**(event_id, user_id)
>
> **group_user**(group_id, user_id)

As an example, how can I return the users who belong to a certain group which belongs to a certain event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a name for this, but you really just want to traverse your relationships with `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    U.*
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN
    Group_user GU
        ON GU.user_id=u.User_id
INNER JOIN
    Event_Group eg
        ON eg.group_id = gu.group_id
WHERE eg.event_id = 1234
```

I added a `DISTINCT` in case a user was in more  than one group that was in the event.

You can also add a `JOIN` to the `events` table if you need another filter (like events taking place on a certain date or whatever).

This is SQL Server syntax but I think it should be basically the same for MySQL, `JOIN` syntax may vary.

Comment: I know you posted this answer a while ago, but I'm trying to learn SQL and wrap my head around joins in my spare time — they're kind of doing my head in. When you select * from users as you did, and then do a join with group_user and then with event_group are you now selecting * from all three of these tables or still just users?

Comment: @bernk In my code only users, because I specify `U.*`.  If you only specified `*` with no table alias before it, then it would return all fields from all tables.